# bootstrap listgroup not centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list

I created a listgroup, but it is not centering on the page. I am able to manipulate the text within each list group to align it left, but the whole element is appearing left on the page. Nothing has allowed me to center this on the page.

CSS:

```
.list-group{
width:40%;
text-align: center;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="span12">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">0</span>
      <b>Stuff1:</b>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">0</span>
      <b>Stuff2: </b></li>

    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">0</span>
      <b>Stuff3:</b></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just add `margin: 0 auto;` for `.list-group`

Answer (score 0):

Answer here.
 Use Following:

```
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand, you need to put in center of your page your `<div>`.
In bootstrap 3 is no css to do it :(
I use this class to `<div>` in center

```
  .centerBlock {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But if you want to align you text, you could use standart classes for it like `text-center`

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap grid classes as

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">

    <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">0</span>
        <b>Stuff1:</b>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">0</span>
      <b>Stuff2: </b>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```